# Why is the last line of this Java code unreachable

Tags: java

I've been writing a parse for a language and I am getting an unexpected problem in Java. Specifically, the Java compiler says that the return statement at the end of this code is unreachable.

```
        StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
        Token tok2;
        do {
            tok2 = tokenizer.nextToken();
            if (tok2 == null) throw new ParseException("Unexected end of file", tok2.endLine, tok2.endColumn);

            switch (tok2.type) {
            case Token.IDENTIFIER:
            case Token.PACKAGE:
                buf.append(tok2.token);
            default:
                throw new ParseException("Illegal character: expected identifier or .", tok.beginColumn, tok.beginLine);
            }

        } while (tok2.type != Token.SEMI_COLON);
        return new PackageElement(buf.toString(), tok.beginLine, tok.beginColumn, tok2.endLine, tok2.endColumn);
```

tok2.type is an int, and the constants are ints, and the ParseException is a checked exception...

I understand what "unreachable" means and I have written many parses both from scratch and via tools like JavaCC, but I have been looking at this code for hours, and it seems correct to me...

Any help understanding why the return statement is unreachable would be much appreciated!

Comment: Sorry, I just worked out what I did - its the switch statement, I need to add a case for the semi-colon!!!

Comment: And a `break` or two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `case`s are missing `break`s, which means each case falls through. That means that one of two things will happen:

- if `tok2 == null`, an exception is thrown
- otherwise, the `switch` block is triggered. Whether or not either `case` is hit, flow falls through to the `default` case, and an exception is thrown

In either case, the first run through the `do` block is guaranteed to throw an exception, and thus anything following it is unreachable.

Solution: add `break` statements, like this:

```
case Token.PACKAGE:
    buf.append(tok2.token);
    break; // <--- here
default:
    // etc
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you reach the semi colon token, the default case is hit and an exception thrown. This is the only exit from the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have a break statement anywhere, which means that the default statement is going to get executed - resulting in an Exception being thrown for certain no matter what. HEnce the return statement will never be hit.